# Error when sending data to Email Template in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**below is my html in Blade**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi {!! $Data->ContractorUserName !!},


        Thanks
    </body>
</html>
```

**below is data that is being passed to Email function Params.**

```
$data = array(
    "ContractorUserName"    =>  $Bid->WhoPlacedBid->UserName
);
```

**Below is the code that sends email**

```
\Mail::send('Project.Emails.Award', array('Data', $data), function($message) 
{
    $message
            ->to('EmailAddress', 'EmailAddress')
            ->subject('hi');
});
```

### **Error Details**

> Undefined variable: Data

Please suggest if I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass data in to the email through the `Mail::send` process, the array isn't actually passed in as a whole - just the individual variables.

Try doing it like this:

```
$data = array(
    "ContractorUserName"    =>  $Bid->WhoPlacedBid->UserName
);

Mail::send('Project.Emails.Award', $data, function($message) 
{
    $message
            ->to('EmailAddress', 'EmailAddress')
            ->subject('hi');
});
```

And then access it in the view like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi {!! $ContractorUserName !!},


        Thanks
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Is there any way to do it like this `$Data->ContractorUserName `

Comment: @PankajGarg I don't believe so at this point, Mail doesn't actually accept objects or arrays when it processes them so for now you're stuck using static variables.